# Changes *in* the weather VS Changes *of* the weather

Tags: grammar

Given the following statement:

Let's hope for a change in/of the weather.

I know the answer should be in the weather but I cannot explain why this is the case. What is the rule here?

Comment: I don't think there's any way you can figure this out without knowing the answer. *A change in the weather* is idiomatic in 21st century English, but people used *a change of the weather* equally often in the early 19th century. [See Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=change+of+the+weather%2C+change+in+the+weather&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cchange%20of%20the%20weather%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchange%20in%20the%20weather%3B%2Cc0). And the meanings of *in* and *of* haven't changed.

Comment: Whatever makes you think there's a “rule”?

Comment: There's a Billie Holiday song....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s a subtle difference.

‘Of the weather’ refers to ‘weather’ as a concept, overall system,or thing, bearing down on you. The bigger picture. A change ‘of the weather’ is a more permanent, general, or likely-to-continue change or trend, overall. Whereas ‘in’ is more local, near you.

**Examples ‘of’:**

- There has been a change of the weather in China. It is now 3 degrees cooler in Summer due to global warming.
- There has been a change of the weather in Mongolia from warmth on the grassy steppes to habitual ice and snow.
- There has been a change of the weather in their relationship - he is now the warm one.

‘In the weather’ refers to the prevailing more local weather currently happening near you.

**Examples ‘In’:**

- There’s been a change in the weather - it’s sunny now
- There’s been a change in the weather - sleet instead of rain yesterday
- There’s been a change in the weather - the storm blew over.

The following article explains prepositions clearly and well, including ‘of’ and ‘in’:

https://medium.com/@english_grammar/how-to-use-preposition-in-english-grammar-on-at-in-of-for-2fdb11e80029

(Despite ‘prepositions’ bring incorrectly written in the singular - perhaps it was written by a Russian. It’s concise though.)

Comment: **+1 I like it!**

Comment: Could you give your authority for this, please?  Otherwise it would be opinion-based.  As it is, I do not think you are correct.  Long term weather patterns are normally referred to as ‘ climate’..

Comment: When having trouble using prepositions correctly, the substitution of a different word and avoiding using prepositions entirely, is indeed an option. However, saying ‘a change of the climate’ or ‘a change in the climate’ means that the prepositions are not in fact avoided and will have similar meanings to those given in my answer. @Tuffy